# how to print with the output of a curl command

Tags: bash

I am trying to execute a script which does a `curl` from a url then `grep` for output then print it.

i tried double quotes and `/` after the special arguments.

```
#!/bin/sh
for URL in `cat curlurl.txt`
do
echo $URL;
curl  -V  $1 "$URL" | grep HTTP/1.1 | awk '{print $2}';
done
```

it just give me `curl` output not the expected.

Comment: Are you sure about that `-V` on `curl`? On my implementation it only prints the version information, totally disregarding other parameters. Looks like you'd want `-I` instead, to only output the HEAD response headers (including the HTTP status code you wish to `grep`)

Comment: As a sidenote, don't do ```for var in `cat file`; do ... done```, do `while IFS='' read -r var; do ... done < file`

Comment: i wanted verbose mode output then grep for HTTP value then print it.

Comment: `-v` for verbose, `-V` for version. But `-I` is more appropriate if you just need the HTTP status code, assuming the server supports HEAD requests (avoid requesting the whole page when only the HTTP status code is needed)

Comment: thank u Aaron, .. sure would use it..

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `curl -V` returs your curl version, not the HTML content.

Secondly, I suggest you adding the `-s` (silent, to mute progressbar) and `-L` (follow redirets, so you are not stuck on a 301 page) and `-I` (print headers) flags.

If you do this, you should be able to grep from the HTML output.

```
curl -ILs https://www.google.com | grep HTTP
HTTP/2 200
```

Comment: thanks for sharing .. also my HTTP version is 1.0.. did not know , i was grepping it for 1.1.. it works now. 
this one works for me.

Comment: #!/bin/sh
  2 for URL in `cat curlurl.txt`
  3 do
  4 echo "$URL";
  5 curl  -ILs  "$URL" | grep HTTP/1* | awk '{print $2}'
  6 done

Comment: Do you need to get status code? Like 200, 500, 400? You can do it simple, without any greps or awk, just use --write-out flag. E.G. curl -Ls -o=/dev/null google.com --write-out "%{http_code}"